# TestNG Selenium Test fails in Ant through command prompt

Tags: selenium, ant, testng

I am using Selenium testNG in eclipse to run my test cases.The testNg.xml file executes the test correctly.

But when I try to run in command prompt through ant the build is success but the test fails.

one peculiar thing happening is : when the driver i use to test is HtmlUnitdriver build is successful and also the test passes . But it fails  when i use other browsers like firefox, chrome, explorer in my test case.

the build.xml i use is:

```
<project name="Automation" default="clean" basedir=".">
    <property name="build.dir" value="${basedir}/build"/>
    <property name="lib.dir" value="${basedir}/lib"/>
    <property name="src.dir" value="${basedir}/src"/>

    <target name="setClassPath">
        <path id="classpath_jars">
            <pathelement path="${basedir}/" />
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
        </path>
        <pathconvert pathsep=":" property="test.classpath" refid="classpath_jars" />
    </target>
    <target name="loadTestNG" depends="setClassPath">
        <taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="${test.classpath}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <tstamp>
            <format property="timestamp" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy_(HH-mm-ss)"/>
        </tstamp>
        <property name="build.log.dir" location="${basedir}/buildlogs"/>
        <mkdir dir="${build.log.dir}"/>
        <property name="build.log.filename" value="build_${timestamp}.log"/>
        <record name="${build.log.dir}/${build.log.filename}" loglevel="verbose" append="false"/>
        <echo message="build logged to ${build.log.filename}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <echo message="deleting existing build directory"/>
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="compile" depends="clean,init,setClassPath,loadTestNG">
        <echo message="classpath:${test.classpath}"/>
        <echo message="compiling.........."/>
        <javac destdir="${build.dir}" srcdir="${src.dir}" classpath="${test.classpath}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="runTests" depends="compile">
        <testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${build.dir}">
            <xmlfileset dir="${basedir}" includes="testNg.xml"/>
        </testng>
    </target>

</project>
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are there any errors from the tests run through the ANT run? Stacktraces?

Comment: Hi dirk  it work fine till compile and generate the class file in the specified folder and when it starts running, it simply specifies the path of the testNg.xml file and simply skips the tests and not showing any error message. it says test failed and buid success. This happens only when my test has to run in any browsers. The same run passes for the headless Htmlunitdriver